# Help Debugging a shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to create a script to do the following:

Lists each directory included in the PATH environment variable

Report if directory exists or not

```
var=${PATH //:/''}
for d in *;
do
if [ -d "$var" ]
then
echo "$var directory exists"
else
echo "Directory does not exist"
fi
```

I get this syntax error when I run the script:

```
/validate_path.sh: line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I would also like to know what is a PATH environment variable?

Comment: this is a much better attempt at doing your homework!  You are missing a final statement in your 'for' loop - the last statement is 'done'  as in `for a bunch of stuff, do <commands>, done`. An environment variable is a storage space where things that might get changed often are stored.  The path variable is what is searched when looking for a program to execute.

Comment: when I use done instead of fi I get:         /validate_path.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./validate_path.sh: line 17: `done '

Comment: Not instead of `fi` -`fi` is the end of your `if` statement.  You need an additional line with `done`

Comment: You need both `fi` and `done`

Comment: Ok thanks for explaining but now the error reads:  /validate_path.sh: line 9: ${PATH //:/''}: bad substitution

Comment: Last hint for the day from me:  Remove the space between `PATH` and `//`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash & http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-shell-script-split-array-383848/#post3270796

Comment: What does removing the space between PATH and // do? My course material doesn't explain what all the meta-characters do quite effectively.

Comment: Its an odd little thing, but easily checked.  At the terminal window, issue the following commands:  `echo $PATH` then `echo ${PATH//:/ }` then `echo ${PATH //:/ }`

Comment: Yes, the first two work but the last command didn't. Good way to test stuff before you script it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is the exact script, you are missing the `done`. The `for` line also has an unnecessary semicolon at the end.

Hint: `-x` and `--debug` options to bash are useful in cases like this.

Example:

```
var=${PATH //:/''}
for d in *; do
   if [ -d "$var" ]; then
      echo "$var directory exists"
   else
      echo "Directory does not exist"
   fi
done
```

This should be syntactically correct, though whether it does what you want is left as an exercise for the reader.